# Using single numbers from Array to print in loop

Tags: java

Ive looked at alot of methods, and they dont seem to work on what im trying to do.
Ive tried hashset and for loop.

```
public static int count(){
        HashSet<Integer> excludedWorlds = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(300, 303, 304, 307));
        for (int i = 300; i < 308; i++) {
            if (excludedWorlds.contains(i)) continue;
            return i;
            // Do stuff
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

so I put

```
public int count =count();
```

then i printed

`count++`

for everyloop but my answer ended up being

`301, then 302, then 303 then 304 then 305.`

but I wanted the answer to be
`301, then 302, then 305, then 306, and loop back to 301` starting over again.
im open any other way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Okay. First, please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array, start with an index value of `-1` and pre-increment while taking the modulus of the array length. Like,

```
private static int[] values = { 301, 302, 305, 306 };
private static int index = -1;

public static int count() {
    return values[++index % values.length];
}
```

This will (as requested) return 301 -> 302 -> 305 -> 306 and then loop back to 301. I tested with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(count());
    }
}
```